# bash filename autocomplete - does it have to use so much screen space?

Tags: command-line, bash, zsh, auto-completion

I have a vague memory of this working in the past, but can't find any info now.

Using TAB in bash to show available filename completions lists them on the line(s) below the command and then reprints the command line. If it might takes a few iterations to actually complete the filename, the screen ends up littered with many lines of partially completed command lines and filename matches.

What I'd like to see is that when I TAB to see the available matches, they show up BELOW the command line. Typing additional characters should then update those matches, and when I'm done with the name, there's just my current command line, with no partial matches still displayed.

Then I don't have umpteen lines of repeated commands and lists of partial completions to ignore when I scroll back through my terminal history.

Maybe I was using a different shell that worked this way?

Comment: I guess you were using `zsh` shell, which provides such a TAB completion behaviour you describe.

Comment: I think you're right, @Thomas. I just re-acquainted myself with `zsh` and I find its "almost" bash compatibility to be maddening.